# How can I compute the differences of 2 unsigned char arrays?

Tags: memory, diff

I have 2 unsigned char arrays and their lengths. And these arrays have "null" char in their content.

How can I find out where they are different, like a diff function in svn? I want a list of the differences, including content to delete or insert or equal.

- `memcmp` just returns equal or not. Not an option.
- String diff libraries are not suitable, because there are '\0' chars in my arrays.

Answer (score 0):

After googling a lot and trying a lot, I achieved my goal by using [libmba](http://www.ioplex.com/~miallen/libmba/).